# TypeError: 'Tk' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

Currently working on a project to display economic data on a dashboard but keep getting this problem in one of my functions. It's slowly eating me alive. Please help!

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter.ttk import Label
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import wbgapi as wb



root = Tk()
root.title("Dashboard")
root.geometry("1920x1080")
root.configure(bg="#555358")
start_year = 2010
end_year = 2022



def display_titles(root):
    Title1 = Label(root, background="#555358", foreground="white", text="Interest Rate", font=("ariel Rounded MT Bold", 28))
    Title3 = Label(root, background="#555358", foreground="white", text="Unemployment", font=("ariel Rounded MT Bold", 28))
    Title4 = Label(root, background="#555358", foreground="white", text="National Debt", font=("ariel Rounded MT Bold", 28))
    Title5 = Label(root, background="#555358", foreground="white", text="Gross Domestic Product", font=("ariel Rounded MT Bold", 28))
    Title6 = Label(root, background="#555358", foreground="white", text="Consumer Price Index", font=("ariel Rounded MT Bold", 28))
    Title1.place(x=233, y=44, anchor="c")
    Title3.place(x=1133, y=44, anchor="c")
    Title4.place(x=233, y=374, anchor="c")
    Title5.place(x=683, y=374, anchor="c")
    Title6.place(x=1133, y=374, anchor="c")

def Plot_data(start_year, end_year):
    wbgapi_id = {
    "Interest": "FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG",
    "GDP": "NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG",
    "CPI": "FP.CPI.TOTL",
    "National Debt": "GC.DOD.TOTL.CN",
    "Unemployment": "SL.UEM.TOTL.ZS",
    }
        # This function plots the data from WGB API
    graph1 = wb.data.DataFrame(wbgapi_id["Interest"], 'GBR', range(start_year, end_year), index='time', numericTimeKeys=True, labels=True).plot(figsize=(4, 3))
    plt.savefig('graph_one.png')

    # Graph 2 was repalced earlier and replaced with a navigation menu

    graph3 = wb.data.DataFrame(wbgapi_id["Unemployment"], 'GBR', range(start_year, end_year), index='time', numericTimeKeys=True, labels=True).plot(figsize=(4, 3))
    plt.savefig('graph_three.png')

    graph4 = wb.data.DataFrame(wbgapi_id["National Debt"], 'GBR', range(2010, 2022), index='time', numericTimeKeys=True, labels=True).plot(figsize=(4, 3))
    plt.savefig('graph_four.png')

    graph5 = wb.data.DataFrame(wbgapi_id["GDP"], 'GBR', range(2010, 2022), index='time', numericTimeKeys=True, labels=True).plot(figsize=(4, 3))
    plt.savefig('graph_five.png')

    graph6 = wb.data.DataFrame(wbgapi_id["CPI"], 'GBR', range(2010, 2022), index='time', numericTimeKeys=True, labels=True).plot(figsize=(4, 3))
    plt.savefig('graph_six.png')

def image(root):
    canvas1 = Canvas(root, height = 260, width = 400)
    canvas1.place(x=33, y=70) 
    img1 = Image.open("graph_one.png")
    canvas1.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1)
    canvas1.create_image(200, 120, image = canvas1.image, anchor = "center")

    canvas2 = Canvas(root, height = 260, width = 400)
    canvas2.place(x=933, y=70)
    img2 = Image.open("graph_two.png")
    canvas2.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
    canvas2.create_image(200, 120, image = canvas2.image, anchor = "center")

    canvas3 = Canvas(root, height = 260, width = 400)
    canvas3.place(x=33, y=400)
    img3 = Image.open("graph_three.png")
    canvas3.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img3)
    canvas3.create_image(200, 120, image = canvas3.image, anchor = "center")

    canvas4 = Canvas(root, height = 260, width = 400)
    canvas4.place(x=483, y=400)
    img4 = Image.open("graph_four.png")
    canvas4.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img4)
    canvas4.create_image(200, 120, image = canvas4.image, anchor = "center")

    canvas5 = Canvas(root, height = 260, width = 400)
    canvas5.place(x=933, y=400)
    img5 = Image.open("graph_five.png")
    canvas5.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img5)
    canvas5.create_image(200, 120, image = canvas5.image, anchor = "center")

    

def dropdown_end_year(root):
# End year selectrion below

    Endyears = ["2010","2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023"]
    var2 = StringVar()
    var2.set(Endyears[12])
    dropdown = OptionMenu(
        root,
        var2,
        *Endyears,
    )
    dropdown.place(x = 775, y = 150, anchor="c")
    end_year = var2.get()

    End_year_label = Label(root, text="End Year", background="#555358", foreground="white", font=("ariel Rounded MT", 20))
    End_year_label.place(x = 650, y = 150, anchor="c")
    return int(end_year)

def dropdown_start_year(root):
    # Start year selection generation below
    start_year_label = Label(root, text="Start Year", background="#555358", foreground="white", font=("ariel Rounded MT", 20))
    start_year_label.place(x = 650, y = 75, anchor="c")

    Startyears = ["2010","2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023"]
    var1 = StringVar()
    var1.set(Startyears[0])
    dropdown = OptionMenu(
        root,
        var1,
        *Startyears,
    )
    dropdown.place(x = 775, y = 75, anchor="c")
    start_year = var1.get()
    start_year = int(start_year)
    return start_year


display_titles(root)
dropdown_end_year(root)
dropdown_start_year(root)
Plot_data(dropdown_start_year(root), root)
image(root)

mainloop()
```

I can't for the life of me take the return value of start_year & end_year and pass it into the '''Plot_data(start_year, end_year)''' without getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\harry\OneDrive - Woodbridge School Email\Documents\Project\GUI.safe.py", line 129, in <module>
    Plot_data(dropdown_start_year(root), root)
  File "c:\Users\harry\OneDrive - Woodbridge School Email\Documents\Project\GUI.safe.py", line 39, in Plot_data
    graph1 = wb.data.DataFrame(wbgapi_id["Interest"], 'GBR', range(start_year, end_year), index='time', numericTimeKeys=True, labels=True).plot(figsize=(4, 3))
TypeError: 'Tk' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and **ask a question** after first making your [best attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to **understand** the problem. "Please help!" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Note well that this is **not a discussion forum**, and we do not provide a debugging service.

Comment: You call `Plot_data()` with `Plot_data(dropdown_start_year(root), root)` - but `Plot_data()` expects `end_year` as the second parameter, not the `Tk()` you assigned to `root`. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You declare `root = Tk()` then later call `Plot_data(dropdown_start_year(root), root)`

Your Plot_data function takes as arguments start_year and end_year. You subsequently use range(start_year, end_year) as an argument when you call:

```
graph1 = wb.data.DataFrame(wbgapi_id["Interest"], 'GBR', range(start_year, end_year), index='time', numericTimeKeys=True, labels=True).plot(figsize=(4, 3))
```

The range method accepts only integers as an argument but you are passing it the end_year variable which you had received as an argument with the value root, which is in turn a Tk object. Don't know what your intention was but you should be passing some entity to end_year that can evaluate to an integer value.